# Node JS, MYSQL connection.query is not a function

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

db_config.js:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'test'
})

connection.connect(function(err){
    if(!!err){
        console.log(err)
    }
    else{
        console.log('Connected')
    }
})

module.export = connection
```

Users.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var connection = require('../db_config')


/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/comments', function(req, res, next) {

  var getCommentsQ = "SELECT * FROM `comments`";

  connection.query(getCommentsQ, function(err, result){
    if(err){
      console.log(err)
      res.send('Unable to get the comments')
    }
    else{
      res.send(result)
    }
  })

});

module.exports = router;
```

Error: Whenever i go to "localhost:3000/users/comments" it says: "connection.query is not a function"

I followed this tutorial: [I was following this tutorial, his worked mine not working](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kUhTmlxsZMo&t=462s&ab_channel=ARCTutorials)

Warning he using Jade im using Ejs, but its not view-engine problem i think

Comment: is it the `module.export = connection` . should be `module.exports`

Comment: Sry you were correct,but im dump and i only erase all of it and only wrote module.exports XD. Problem solved btw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in your export, try exporting your `connection` like this.

```
module.exports = connection;
```

Comment: Don't post a real answer for typos. Just comment and vote to close (or flag as a typo if you don't have enough rep to vote).